# Interacting with existing Smart Contract deployed on test network like rinkeby from local test environment (truffle)

Tags: web3js, truffle, ethereumjs, rinkeby, truffle-test

I have forked rinkeby network using ganache-cli as shown below

ganache-cli -f https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/id --account="fsdfmsadklksmdflskamf"

Now, I want to test my smart contract which has dependencies of smart contract present on rinkeby network.

how to create interface of existing smart contract from rinkeby in truffle
So that we can interact with them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Btw you can now open a ticket with truffle support: https://www.trufflesuite.com/community https://trufflesuite.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/new